# Parent form is bringing to front when the menu strip of a child form is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menustrip

I have a pretty strange but reproductible problem.

I have a `MenuStrip` which can open a new Modeless form with the `Form.Show()` method.

The child form also have a Menu Strip.

The strange stuff happens when you start by clicking the menu strip of the child form. Then the parent form is coming back foreground and saying hello. That's a real pain.

How to prevent this problem?

A Scorcese movie to illustrate my problem by following this link [zippyshare.com](http://www44.zippyshare.com/v/4833978/file.html) (3Mo)

As you can see in the video, parent form doesn't take focus, it is just bringed front by somehing else.

Note that repacing the `MenuStrip` by a `ToolStrip` correct the problem.

Some Code to reproduce the problem:

```
public class DemoLostfocus : Form
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.menuStrip1 = new MenuStrip();
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.openModelessFormToolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] {
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem});
        this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
        this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 24);
        this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";

        this.fileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] {
        this.openModelessFormToolStripMenuItem});
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Name = "fileToolStripMenuItem";
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = "File";

        this.openModelessFormToolStripMenuItem.Name = "openModelessFormToolStripMenuItem";
        this.openModelessFormToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(187, 22);
        this.openModelessFormToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Open Modeless Form";
        this.openModelessFormToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.openModelessFormToolStripMenuItem_Click);

        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
        this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
        this.Name = "DemoLostfocus";
        this.Text = "DemoLostfocus";
        this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
    }

    private MenuStrip menuStrip1;
    private ToolStripMenuItem fileToolStripMenuItem;
    private ToolStripMenuItem openModelessFormToolStripMenuItem;

    public DemoLostfocus()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void openModelessFormToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new DemoLostfocus()).Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that your form is spawning a new instance of itself.  That could cause lots of problems. Better spawn an instance of something else.

Comment: I don't see what kind of problem this could do. Have you an example?

Comment: No, I don't have an example. If I did, I would have written an answer, not a comment. But you have two identically named parentless forms containing identically named controls. I would suspect this to be the problem before I suspect anything else.

Comment: Also, it could possibly be that the object created by `(new DemoLostfocus()).Show();` gets garbage-collected immediately after it is created. That could be the source of lots of problems, too.

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to happen on .Net 3.5, but it does repro on .Net 4.0.

Comment: Using `new DemoLostfocus().Show(this);` seems to solve the problem, but now it takes two clicks to open the child menu.

Comment: That's less annoying! Still annoying, but far more less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty nasty bug that was introduced in .NET 4.5.  The KB article is [available here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2769674).  The fix is right now only available as a hotfix, hopefully it will make it into a service update soon.  I'll just copy/paste the description:

> Assume that you have a .NET Framework 4.5-based Windows Form application. When you click a menu item to open a child window in the application, interactions with the menu and child window behave incorrectly.
>
> For example, you may experience the following:
>
> When you open a context menu in the child window, the main window takes the focus.
> You cannot use mnemonics to access a menu item.
>
> This issue occurs because the IMessageFilter interface is unhooked too aggressively. Therefore, the .NET Framework 4.5 does not filter menu-related window messages.

---

Update: this issue was fixed in a .NET 4.5 update released on Jan 8th, 2013.  The KB article [is here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750149).

Comment: Ok, so I lost against the framework, I will just use a ToolStrip!

Comment: Unfortunately the patch works only on Windows 8, not windows 7 so far :-/