# Win Form in front of parent form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form containing a button to create a new derived class form. In the callback for this button, I have the code

```
 AnotherFormClass newForm= new AnotherFormClass();
 newForm.Show();
```

When the button is clicked and this runs, the newForm momentarily flashes up in front of the original form on my screen, but then the original form comes back to the front.  I don't want to use brute force TopMost() it to force newForm to always be in front.  Plus, I'm not sure why I'm seeing this behaviour.  Could anyone help please?  I see there is an article mentioning a slightly similar problem here -
[Parent form is bringing to front when the menu strip of a child form is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160033/parent-form-is-bringing-to-front-when-the-menu-strip-of-a-child-form-is-clicked)
but this is for .NET 4.5 and I've encountered this behaviour in 4.0 before too.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Whats wrong with TopMost()?

Comment: @BrandonJ because the user might want to use other apps

Comment: The issue with TopMost is that it will make that form always be on top, not just when it gets constructed.  Also, if I set the parent and the child form to be TopMost=true, then I see the same problem as before (child form flashes up in front then goes behind the parent)

Comment: There must be something bringing the first from back on top automatically. I don't think the problem is in how you create the new form or how you show it, instead I think there is something in the original form that is sending the new form back or putting itself on top after the new form is created.

Comment: I would have thought so, but I can't see anything - it's a very simple form - just a listView and a button.  Let me try to strip it down further and I'll report back..

Answer (score 2):

***" the newForm momentarily flashes up in front of the original form on my screen, but then the original form comes back to the front."***

If you mean that you always need the sub-form to be in front

use `Form.ShowDialog()` method, which will keep the sub-form in front until you close it.

In your case

```
 var newForm= new AnotherFormClass();
 newForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Read more about [Form.ShowDialog Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

Comment: This makes the child form go in front, but I would also like the option of make it go behind again by clicking on the parent form.

Comment: That is what I originally tried to do!  As I said, when I do this, the form momentarily appears in front of the parent form (I guess as it is constructed) and then the parent form goes back in front.  I don't have TopMost=true for the parent form.

Comment: @ChrisW: You mean it automatically goes to back?

Comment: Yes, the parent form comes to the front and the new child form (which was momentarily at the front) goes to the back

Comment: @ChrisW:Do you have any code after `newForm.Show();` which affect the form status?

Comment: @HD As far as I can see, no - only a button and a listView.  I'm going to try strip it down further today and create a simpler example.  I'll report back.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show the new form as a child of the current form:

```
newForm.Show(this);
```

Comment: this will *keep* the child on top which it doesnt sound like he necessarily wants