# c# winforms - How can I get the child form in front of parent form without making the parent one invisible?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This question is not a duplicate of [Win Form in front of parent form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702941/win-form-in-front-of-parent-form)

because the author of that one didn't seem to mind if the parent form was hidden, and the answers suggesting ShowDialog() hide the parent. I don't want the parent form hidden.

I have the following code in form_load

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var childform = new Form();           
        childform.Show();
        childform.BringToFront();           
        childform.Activate();
    }
```

Yet it won't show the child in front of the parent. It shows this, as you can see, it's showing the parent form in front and the child behind, rather than the other way around which I want.

[image]

I've read of using `childform.ShowDialog()`   but I don't want that because that would make the parent invisible while the child form shows.  I want both visible.

I've read that BringToFront won't work 'cos it's for controls not forms, and to use Activate, but as you can see i've tried Activate and it isn't working either.

Comment: If you want the child form to always stay in front of parent form, you can make the parent form owner of the child form. For instance, `childform.Show(this);`.

Comment: When do you want to do that? After load, in a click o a button...? You can call parentForm.SendToBack();

Comment: @user1845593  I don't know what you mean. There is no button.  That code is as I said "in form_load"

Comment: Which now I see is mentioned in the linked question answers. So it really sounds to me as duplicate.

Comment: @IvanStoev I want the parent to remain visible. can you show me any answer that covers that? The question I linked to didn't have that stipulation.

Comment: ShowDialog does not make the calling form invisible. It makes the dialog modal, but the caller remains visible.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar yes it does,  until the called form is closed. And I don't want that. I want both forms to appear. I'll make an edit to show that it does

Comment: No it doesn't. Maybe you should check your definition of invisible... The caller will not be invisible.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar When using ShowDialog() on the called, the the calling form is not viewable on screen until the called form is closed.  Maybe you don't want to call that invisible. But I mean the calling form is not viewable on screen with ShowDialog().

Comment: There are only two answers and both suggest passing the form as an owner to `Show` or `ShowDialog`. There is nothing related to hiding the parent form in these solutions.

Comment: @IvanStoev  When I do `childform.ShowDialog(this); ` as you suggest, it still doesn't make the parent one remain visible

Comment: Do you mean you can not activate it? Try your code in the form's "Shown" event. That way the second form is shown after the main form and should become active.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar is right of course. Neither call makes the parent form invisible. There must be some other code (yours) that does that. Can you provide [mcve]?

Comment: I guess now that instead of invisible he means the form will not be shown in the first place as he does this in the Form's load event - in that case the dialog will be shown before the main form is visible.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar you can post that as an answer i'll certainly upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your code in the form's `Shown` event. That way the second form is shown after the main form and should thus become active.

Comment: thanks, this works and it also works for ShowDialog() too and it shows the reason why what I had wasn't working. Tommy's answer elaborates, though your commetn was fairly clear and came earlier

Answer (score 3):

Form.Show() method has an overload that taken in an argument that specifies the parent of the form. Th child form is always shown above the parent form.

```
childForm.Show(this); //this is the parent form
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply move the action to Shown event. You can remove both BringToFront and Activiate.

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var childform = new Form();
    childform.Show();
}
```

It is because when Load event is called, the form is yet shown.

As a result, your sequence becomes undesirably:

1. Parent Load > Call Child
2. Child Load
3. Child Shown
4. Parent Shown

Therefore, your parent is shown later and thus anyway is upper.

By using Shown event, the issue solved.

1. Parent Load
2. Parent Shown > Call Child
3. Child Load
4. Child Shown

Comment: yeah thanks, good explanation..  Thorsten's comment beat you to the answer  though.. It's a good idea to post a brief answer first then put any expansion into it, with an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just include `this` as a parameter to the `Show` method.

```
var childform = new Form();
childform.Show(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this after InitializeComponent():

```
this.Activated += (s, e) => ((Form)s).SendToBack();
```

where "this" is the parent form, so I'm casting "s" to Form